# Parachain stuck at authoring runtime upgrade block

Tags: parachain, runtime-upgrade, error, parachain-collator, networking

Our testnet parachain is stuck exactly at the block in which the runtime upgrade is authored. It was authorized and enacted via `parachainSystem` as recommended. The upgrade neither includes any migrations nor larger code changes, the previous upgrade was just as large (~3.6mb) and included many migrations without any issue.

Since we have full control over the relay chain, we tried unstucking it by forcing new parachain code on the relay via `sudo.paras.forceSetCurrentCode`. Unfortunately, that did not have any effect.

**I would really appreciate any insights about this issue as I was under the impression that a relaychain can ALWAYS unblock a parachain**. So there needs to be a solution, I could not find it though unfortunately. Maybe we can manually force discarding the block for collators?

---

Of course, we have checked [this answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/876/280) regarding a stuck parachain block production:

- *Possible issue #1 (trouble sending the block)*: The PoV size is quite large with ~3.6mb. However, validators and collators are physically close and the network connection between these should not be an issue AFAICT.
- *Possible issue #2 (trouble verifying the block in time)*: This should not be an issue as block proposal preparation is 10 to 20ms
- *Possible issue #3 (Invalid parachain code in the relay)*: Since both above ones should not apply, we tried forcing parachain code via relay. As stated above, this did not yield any effects.

**The two log lines which stand out**

```
WARN tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: [Relaychain] distribute collation message parent is outside of our view relay_parent=0x5edb8867f6ac41d67e3e545926379b8db05d9d388f9c08ce4c52e341b645d7a3
INFO tokio-runtime-worker aura: [Parachain] ⌛️ Discarding proposal for slot 141223015; block production took too long
```

Based [on this response](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/6732/280) about the *"block production took too long"*, we stopped all parachain nodes and then brought back a single collator hoping the transaction would leave the tx pool due to hitting mortality limit. That did not happen unfortunately. First we kept the nodes offline for ~10 minutes, then ~30 minutes, then hours. The issue persists after 12 hours.

---

**Testnet setup**

- 2 Relay nodes with full control
- Relay spec based on `rococo-local`
- 3 Collators with full control

Comment: Can you post an RPC link? I want to replay the block locally. It may be possible to blacklist all transactions and blocks that take too long in the chainspec.

Comment: Sure, thanks for getting back to me. Somehow, I got the parachain to produce blocks again. I just kept trying keeping collators off for > 10 minutes and forcing different para WASMs on the relay.

Block before upgrade and long stall (#216,951): https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss://fullnode.algol.cntrfg.com#/explorer/query/0xc82319950f3dbf0c65f524a53395a23117ac0103ef57ae1f8f8d7be29be10bb0

Runtime upgrade block (#216,952): https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss://fullnode.algol.cntrfg.com#/explorer/query/216952